# linker error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, linker, ld

I am trying to compile a very simple C++ program using CMake, but keep having an issue.
Following is the directory structure:

```
CompileTest
 |---CMakeLists.txt (A)
 |---src
      |---CMakeLists.txt (B)
      |---main.cc
      |---exec
          |---CMakeLists.txt (C)
          |---exec.cc
          |---exec.hh
```

CMakeLists.txt (A):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(multi_file)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")

add_subdirectory(src)
```

CMakeLists.txt (B):

```
add_subdirectory("exec")

add_executable(out main.cc)
```

CMakeLists.txt (C):

```
add_library(exec SHARED exec.cc)
```

exec.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "exec.hh"

float exec_func(int input)
{
   return 0.42f;
}
```

exec.hh:

```
#ifndef EXEC_HH_
#define EXEC_HH_

float exec_func(int input);

#endif
```

main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "exec/exec.hh"

int main ()
{
   float test = exec_func(2);
   std::cout << "test value: " << test << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

To run the build:

1. Create a build-dir at the CMakeLists.txt(A) level
2. cd into it
3. run `cmake ../`
4. run `make`

If it makes any difference: I am running this test in a docker VM (Ubuntu, gcc12) with a mounted directory

I keep getting the following error:

```
root@13e768aH4187:/docker-test/CompileTest/builddir# make
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/out.dir/main.cc.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable out
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/out.dir/main.cc.o: in function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `exec_func(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/out.dir/build.make:97: src/out] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:115: src/CMakeFiles/out.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I am confused because all the functions are defined, and I did not see any compilation error. To my understanding, this is caused by a linker error (hence the ld).

Would you mind pointing out what is the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: The hint: target_link_library out to exec is missing.

Comment: You may find [this](https://github.com/MhmRhm/CMakeProjectTemplate) useful. It is based on a book called [Modern CMake for C++](https://www.packtpub.com/product/modern-cmake-for-c/9781801070058). In your case I believe you should use [target_link_libraries(out PRIVATE exec)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)